# ImageView Animation

Tags: animation, uiimageview, imageview, frame

I have 1 image that i want it to move across the screen. in my case its an image of a little motorcycle that rides form left to right across the screen.
I there any way to take this one image & make it move one step every time for make it like animation image? instead of taking a lot of pictures frame by frame and make animation from it because in my case i have 367 pictures & it makes the project very big.
Thanks.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *animation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display it in an UIImageView and animate the view itself:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:motorcycleImage];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

And when you want to animate it:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
CGRect rect = imgView.rect;
rect.origin.x += 320 - rect.size.width;
// EDIT: how to put the view on the bottom of the screen
rect.origin.y += 480 - rect.size.height;
imgView.rect = rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but it give me 2 errors where the rect word in the code: propery 'rect' not found on object of type 'UIImageView*'

Comment: Thanks i did it but how can i make the motorcycle to come in from out of the screen, left to right & repeat the animation. for now it apears in the top of the screen & i want it at the bottom.

Comment: Modify its frame property to appear at the bottom and call [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount] to how much times you want the animation to repeat

Comment: i set [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount= 20] for example, but it doesnt work & i can't seem to find how to put it in the bottom :\

Comment: doesn't work, doesn't work, doesn't work... I can't help if you keep shouting this... WHAT does not work? What EXACTLY is the error? (hint: to put it into the bottom, modify its frame's origin.y property to a higher value. The view's and the screen's top left corner is (0, 0) and y grows by going down, and x grows by going right, so the code in the edit will work...)

Comment: i posted an answer upwards with my problem